# JpaStateMachineRepository not available in Spring StateMachine 2.0.0

Tags: spring-statemachine

After creating project via spring **Initializr** https://start.spring.io/
with option **Statemachine** checked.

If I try to autowaire JpaStateMachineRepository then  I get 
JpaStateMachineRepository cannot be resolved to a type.

There is no import option. I have **spring-statemachine-bom** in my pom and I beleive it has spring-data-jpa already dependancy covered already.

I am migrating from 1.2.8 to 2.0.0. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start.spring.io` only adds `spring-statemachine-starter` which effectively only adds `spring-statemachine-autoconfigure`. `spring-statemachine-bom` only adds dependency management, not dependencies itself.

You just need to import below dep manually:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-statemachine-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

We're probably going to add more starters for usual use cases. `JPA` seem to be one of those which could have its own statemachine related starter.